# Internet connection issues on Yosemite

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, osx-yosemite

I'm having troubles with internet connectivity on Yosemite, MacBook Pro (late 2014).

When I'm at home internet works great. I'm connected through wifi to a standard modem/router. The problem is when I'm at the office. Here we have a Netgear modem/router and connection doesn't work well. It works for anyone else in the office without any problem (they are not on Mac) and it works well on my phone (Android), so I determine that it is a problem with OS X only. For example, when internet doesn't work on my computer I check my phone and it works great there.

There are things that always work:

- I can connect to the network without problems.
- DNS resolution works well. I tested this by doing ping domain.com and see IP gets resolved correctly.
- Ping works well.
- The diagnose tool (System Perferences > Network > Assist me...) says everything is OK. Also the wifi diagnose tool when you click the wifi icon while pressing the option key says everything is OK (at the same time that browser is not working).

However, I cannot browse reliably on any browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) or perform some other HTTP tasks like curl on the command line. It is not that it doesn't work at all. It does some times, probably 50% of the time it works, but the other 50% I'm getting timeouts, which is really annoying.

Some info about the router and connection:

- It is not dual band. Only 2.4 GHz
- Channel is set to auto and seems to always select channel 1
- My wifi connection shows it is connected at 2.4 GHz, channel 1, 802.11n

I tried the following things without success:

- Clean install of Yosemite to avoid broken config files
- Changing connection MTU (1400, 1450)
- Removing security from network
- Restarting discoverd

Anything else that I can try?

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work". What specific errors are you getting? What is the behavior of the browser when problems happen, since you mention connecting, pinging, and DNS resolution work well.

Comment: What was the lowest MTU you tried? Which "diagnose tool" did you run (I can think of 4 built-in network diagnostics tools in OS X off the top of my head)? Is the office Netgear router dual-band? If so, what band is your MBP connecting on (maybe your MBP is using 5GHz and everything else is using 2.4GHz, and your office Netgear router is having a problem in 5GHz)? How did you test DNS resolution? Not all DNS tools use discoveryd like the GUI apps do, so it's possible discoveryd-based DNS lookups are having a problem you won't see with, say, "nslookup".

Comment: When I say it doesn't work is that I get timeouts and it says it cannot connect. DNS works well when I tested from ping. When I do ping domain.com it resolves to the IP without problem. However if later I do curl http://domain.com it doesn't work (timeout). The diagnose tool I used is the one you access through the network configuration screen after clicking on 'Assist me...'. I tested MTU 1400. I will update the question to make it clearer.